# Signup page not opening in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Having an login.html it has `SignUp Button` while click on it its not opening the `signup.html` page

index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm">
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign-In" name="login-view">
    <ion-content class="padding">
     <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signup()">SignUp</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngMockE2E','ui.router'])
    .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            if (cordova.platformId === 'ios' && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
        });
    })

    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, USER_ROLES) {
        $stateProvider

  .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
        .state('signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
            controller: 'SignupCtrl'
        })
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    })
```

controller.js

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
    $scope.username = AuthService.username();

    $scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized, function (event) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Unauthorized!',
            template: 'You are not allowed to access this resource.'
        });
    });

    $scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, function (event) {
        AuthService.logout();
        $state.go('login');
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Session Lost!',
            template: 'Sorry, You have to login again.'
        });
    });

    $scope.setCurrentUsername = function (name) {
        $scope.username = name;
    };
})

        .controller("SignupCtrl", function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {
                $scope.data = {};
                $scope.signup = function () {
                    $state.go('singup');
                };
            })

    .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {
        $scope.data = {};

        $scope.login = function (data) {
            AuthService.login(data.username, data.password).then(function (authenticated) {
                $state.go('main.dash', {}, { reload: true });
                $scope.setCurrentUsername(data.username);
            }
        };
    })
```

and inside the `templates folder` is having `signup.html`

```
<ion-view view-title="Signup" name="Signup-view">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
      <form id="signup-form2" class="list ">

    // sign up fields goes here.....

     <a ui-sref="login" id="signup-button5" style="border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;" class="button button-calm button-block" ng-click="signupEmail(data)">Sign up</a>
       </form>
     </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Comment: Where's your login state declaration and controller? Or have you just left them out of this example?

Comment: thank you! So there's no error logs in console what so ever?

Comment: no such console error log. right now

Comment: Yes, and I'm not sure if it's a typo but if your controller `SignupCtrl` has the function `$scope.signup` it won't work in the login page. You have to have the signup and state.go functions in your loginCtrl.

Comment: @thepio actually LoginCtrl its working fine but I dont understand same thing cant work for signup.

Comment: Hmmm I was about to suggest a chat but creating the chatroom doesn't seem to work for some reason. But can you share your login controller also? I'm thinking that you don't have the signup function in your login controller. I'm actually going to make an answer of it so you can understand what I'm saying and no need to chat in the comments so much.

Comment: i have added LoginCtrl in controller.js

Comment: $state.go not opening the page on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the state change function in your `LoginCtrl`. So you should have it declared in the `LoginCtrl` because that controller is used in the login.html.

```
.controller("LoginCtrl", function ($scope, $state) {
  $scope.signup = function () {
    $state.go('signup');
  };
})
```

Also consider that in your example code you had a typo in the `$state.go` function. Your state name is `singup` when it should be `signup`.

Comment: I dont have declared the SignupCtrl inside the LoginCtrl both are differnt in scope.

Comment: No but you need to declare the `ng-click="signup()"` in your `LoginCtrl`. So let's say you have `<button ng-click="awesomeFunction()">Awesome</button>` in your login.html then you need to have the `awesomeFunction` declared in your `LoginCtrl` like this `$scope.awesomeFunction = function() { alert('this is awesome'); }`. Hopefully I'm clear what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Thanks for reply I done changes as per your suggestions. it prompted the alert but not opening the page.

Comment: Just to make sure....you tried adding it like this also `<button ng-click="signup()">Signup</button>` in your login.html and in your login controller you placed `$scope.signup = function() { $state.go('signup'); }`?

Comment: .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function (data) {

    };
    $scope.signup = function () {
      //  $state.go('signup');
        alert('Hi');
    };

}) done this change but not opening page

Comment: Hmm ok. What is you `AppCtrl` since you have declared it in your body? There seems to be a lot of unknowns in this question and I'm not sure if I can help you.